# Buffer an input signal while maintaining the same input waveform undistorted

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

The above shows an amplitude modulated (AM) signal. I was just wondering how can I make the AM waveform have a very low impendence so that it is able to transmit high power.

One solution I tried is using an op-amp as buffer which can reduce impedance while keeping the shape of waveform same as before, but the problem is the op-amp cannot produce enough output power of, say, 10 watts to the antenna.

I think I basically need an op-amp which can produce a good amount of power.

Comment: What frequency, and do you have licensing/permission to transmit high power on that frequency? With that in mind, an op amp is not a power amp, and isn't the best technique here.

Comment: What you need is an RF power amplifier. For 10 W, it will probably not be as simple as a single OP amp.

Comment: Your AM signal shown in your question is not correctly filtered hence, it has non-coinciding positive and negative peaks. (FYI)

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two ways to do an AM transmitter, generate a low level AM signal and amplify it using a linear power amplifier, or do high level modulation in the power amplifier stages.

The advantage of the second method is that the RF power amplifier can be biased Class C so it runs more efficiently. The disadvantage is you need high power audio and a modulation transformer. This is how most CB radios do it though.

You may be able to get a power opamp that will work at the frequency you want (which you haven't specified) but they are generally relatively expensive, you would probably be better off using a transistor amplifier. Whichever type of amplifier you use would need impedance matching and filtering.

That said, there's still the question of legality. What you're trying to do is going to be illegal in most countries. In the U.S. for example, transmitters outside of very low power and amateur radio use need to be type accepted. If you really want to build transmitters I would recommend looking into ham radio. It will take some time and effort to get licensed to the level where you can legally build transmitters, but you will learn a lot along the way.